# Can't Upload File to Google Cloud Storage with PHP Client Library

Tags: php, google-cloud-storage, google-api-php-client

I want this script to upload a text file to a bucket in my Google Cloud Storage Account.  I'm using the PHP Client Library, specifically the objects.insert method.  The script seems to work up until I actually call the insert method (if I cancel that line out, then I can at least see the results from the var_dump).  If I call the method, I get a HTTP 500 - Internal Server Error (and the file does not make it to my Cloud Storage account).

Some things to note:

- This script is for a service account
- The text file is in the same folder as this script

I think there's something wrong with the way I'm calling insert, but I can't figure it out.  I'd appreciate any suggestions on how to make this script work so that the text file uploads.

Here's the code:

```
<?php
    require_once 'lib/src/Google_Client.php'; 
    require_once 'lib/src/contrib/Google_StorageService.php';

    define("CLIENT_ID", "MY-CLIENT-ID");
    define("SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME", "MY-SERVICE-ACCOUNT-NAME");

    define("KEY_FILE", "/path/to/privatekey.p12");

    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName("Google Cloud Storage Test Connection");

    session_start();
    if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
        $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
    }

    // Load the key in PKCS 12 format (you need to download this from the
    // Google API Console when the service account was created.
    $key = file_get_contents(KEY_FILE);
    $client->setAssertionCredentials(new Google_AssertionCredentials(
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME,
        array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write'),
        $key)
    );

    $client->setClientId(CLIENT_ID);

    //Define Storage Service
    $storageService = new Google_StorageService($client);
    $objects = $storageService -> objects;

    //Define Storage Object
    $gso = new Google_StorageObject ();
    $gso-> setName('myObj');

    //Define Storage Object Media
    $gsoMedia = new Google_StorageObjectMedia ();
    $gsoMedia-> setContentType('text/plain');
    $gsoMedia-> setData(file_get_contents('Test.txt'));

    //Link Storage Object Media to Storage Object
    $gso-> setMedia($gsoMedia);

    //Upload to Cloud Storage
    $result = $objects->insert(/*MY_BUCKET*/,  $gso);

    var_dump($gso);

?>
```

Comment: for 500 errors, check your server's error log. there'll be more details there than the useless "something happened" you see in a browser.

Comment: yep, hard to determine what's going wrong without the error message

Comment: I've been working on this in WebMatrix and the only error codes I could see there was the 500 one.  Then I uploaded the script to my server and I immediately got an error about an unexpected T_CONSTANT.  I changed the format of my constant declarations and now I'm getting this error (it's really long so I'll link to a screenshot): http://www.flickr.com/photos/92966180@N08/9125897877/

Comment: I adjusted my .htaccess file so that I'm using PHP 5.3, but I still get this: http://www.flickr.com/photos/92966180@N08/9128246300/

Comment: Is test.txt over 64KB? Setting the data as part of the media object like that won't work if the file is over 64KB. Regardless, you may want to upload the object using `Google_MediaFileUpload` instead.

Comment: Also, since the time when you asked this question, a newer version of the GCS API has made it into the Google PHP API client. I would suggest migrating, although the latest version no longer supports the upload method demonstrated above.

Comment: Is anyone still experiencing this issue?  If so, can you provide the error logs and the Google PHP API calls being made?